# How to get iTunes app description?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

How do I obtain the iTunes Store app description from within my iPhone app? I need it to make a "help" screen in my app.

I don't know if this is possible, but I know there are special link to make the user go to reviews of apps and so maybe it's also possibile to get the app description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the iTunes search APIs:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can load the description from a remote site and store it localy. This way you are able to update the information without updating the whole app. You could load an HTML file, store it to the Documents directory and show it within your app with a UIWebView.